# Why I got more than one client hello when using wireshark capture packages?

Tags: networking, https, tcp, wireshark

3 client hello was send, and 3 server hello sends back.
192.168.199.236 is my Mac's ip addr.[detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvNqK.png)

There are more than one client hello/server hello when building HTTPS connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at three different connections, not one.  Notice that the port numbers are different.

In other words, you are not seeing three server and client hellos in one connection, you are looking at three different connections, each of which has a handshake.